# jQuery selectmenu popup style not working

Tags: jquery

I've used jQuery ThemeRoller to generate JS/CSS: [custom ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/?ffDefault=Arial%2CHelvetica%2Csans-serif&fsDefault=0.87em&fwDefault=normal&cornerRadius=5px&bgColorHeader=%23e9e9e9&bgTextureHeader=flat&borderColorHeader=%23dddddd&fcHeader=%23333333&iconColorHeader=%23444444&bgColorContent=%23ffffff&bgTextureContent=flat&borderColorContent=%23dddddd&fcContent=%23333333&iconColorContent=%23444444&bgColorDefault=%238a8a8a&bgTextureDefault=flat&borderColorDefault=%23848484&fcDefault=%23ffffff&iconColorDefault=%23777777&bgColorHover=%23ededed&bgTextureHover=flat&borderColorHover=%23cccccc&fcHover=%232b2b2b&iconColorHover=%23555555&bgColorActive=%23ffffff&bgTextureActive=flat&borderColorActive=%23848484&fcActive=%23000000&iconColorActive=%23ffffff&bgColorHighlight=%23cacaca&bgTextureHighlight=flat&borderColorHighlight=%239c9c9c&fcHighlight=%234d4d4d&iconColorHighlight=%23484848&bgColorError=%23fddfdf&bgTextureError=flat&borderColorError=%23f1a899&fcError=%235f3f3f&iconColorError=%23cc0000&bgColorOverlay=%23aaaaaa&bgTextureOverlay=flat&bgImgOpacityOverlay=0&opacityOverlay=30&bgColorShadow=%23666666&bgTextureShadow=flat&bgImgOpacityShadow=0&opacityShadow=30&thicknessShadow=5px&offsetTopShadow=0px&offsetLeftShadow=0px&cornerRadiusShadow=8px&bgImgOpacityHeader=&bgImgOpacityContent=&bgImgOpacityDefault=&bgImgOpacityHover=&bgImgOpacityActive=&bgImgOpacityHighlight=&bgImgOpacityError=)

but when I edit the provided index.html file and change:

```
$( "#selectmenu" ).selectmenu();
```

to

```
$( "#selectmenu" ).selectmenu({style:'popup'});
```

and test the index.html file in Chrome, the selectmenu is 'dropdown' whereas I would like the 'popup' style.

I've created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BartmanEH/o4xc71of/40/CDN) linked to CDN hosted .js and .css files.

How do I get the selectmenu to have popup style (menu centered on selected option) instead of dropdown style (menu always drops down from first option)?

Comment: share your test code on fiddle/punkler/whatever ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that jQuery has removed 'popup' selectmenu functionality in some recent version leaving only 'dropdown' style. Perhaps this has to do with the development of the jQuery Mobile package that features 'popup' style as the [custom selectmenu](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/selectmenu-custom/).

I think I will convert my project from jQuery UI to jQuery Mobile since it's supposed to be used mainly with mobile devices anyway.